# regarding 20 scheduled jobs limit on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

Google App Engine does not allow us to schedule more than 20 cron jobs. I'm wondering if there is a way to schedule more jobs in a single go.

Comment: e.g. if the last scheduled job is to over-write cron.yaml with new jobs. Will this work?

Comment: No, this won't work. You need to use another method to schedule your tasks. Essentially you need to trigger them with a request to the site from another computer, or you need to use Task Queues as I describe below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Google App Engine - Task Queues vs Cron Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027778/google-app-engine-task-queues-vs-cron-jobs).

It will give you some ideas for how you can replace some cron jobs with tasks. This is the only way to do more things that are not user initiated, other than having multiple accounts that each do a separate thing.