# How can Google App Engine be prevented from immediately rescheduling tasks after status code 500?

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, task-queue

I have a Google App Engine servlet that is `cron` configured to run once a week. Since it will take more than 1 minute of execution time, it launches a task (i.e. another servlet `task/clear`) on the application's default push task queue.

Now what I'm observing is this: if the task causes an exception (e.g. `NullPointerException` inside its second servlet), this gets translated into HTTP status 500 (i.e. `HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR`) and Google App Engine apparently reacts by immediately relaunching the same task again. It announces this by printing:

```
Web hook at http://127.0.0.1:8888/task/clear returned status code 500.  Rescheduling..
```

I can see how this can sometimes be a [feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027778/google-app-engine-task-queues-vs-cron-jobs), but in my scenario it's inappropriate. Can I request that Google App Engine should not do such automatic rescheduling, or am I expected to use other status codes to indicate error conditions that would not cause rescheduling by its rules? Or is this something that happens only on the dev. server?

BTW, I am currently also running other tasks (with different frequencies) on the same task queue, so throttling reschedules on the level of task queue configuration would be inconvenient (so I hope there is another/better option too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push#Java_Task_execution - the task must return a response code between 200 and 299.

You can either return the correct value, set the taskRetryLimit in RetryOptions or check the header X-AppEngine-TaskExecutionCount when task launches to check how many times it has been launched and act accordingly.

Comment: +1 `X-AppEngine-TaskExecutionCount` will allows me to do an extra safety check inside the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution: in the Java API, there is a method [`RetryOptions#taskRetryLimit`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/RetryOptions#taskRetryLimit%28int%29), which serves my case.